# Problem with Xcode and UIScrollView

Tags: iphone, interface-builder, uiscrollview

I do not seem to be able to get a working connection between an outlet in the code and with the actual object in interface builder.

I have a UIScrollview in my XIB and this in my .h

```
 IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollView;
```

Now I connected the object with the outlet and I also see the connection when I look at the Connection Inspector. In my .m class file I have the method awakeFromNib which is called. Here I want to get the width and height from the UIScrollView.

```
 NSLog(@"Scrollview : %f,%f",scrollView.frame.size.width,scrollView.frame.size.height);
```

But all I get is this :

> Scrollview : 0.000000,0.000000

I can say for sure that it has a size of 320 by 160 in Interface Builder.

Any idea ??

Comment: Add that NSLog-statement to viewDidLoad as well and see what happens.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, Till gave a good hint. It works with viewDidLoad and not with awakeFromNib. However I still do not know why, since my understanding was that awakeFromNib will be called when all connections are ready.

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to scroll view, tricky happens, you need to set the basic settings based on docs, and if you want it scroll, make the scroll view bigger than the screen size, try 600,600. and also, try getting the size within viewdidload, and see what happens.